# Cannot specify a path to an Excel file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

It's a good day, everyone. I'm a Javascript beginner. $.ig.Excel.Workbook() I found and am using the API. What I want here is to load the existing Excel file.

Below is the code I'm using. If I use it like this, the error 'Uncaught Error: invalid values' appears.

```js
function createFormattingWorkbook(ReportTableArray) {
  var data = ReportTableArray;
  var Price;
  var dataURL1 = canvas1.toDataURL(1.0);
  var dataURL2 = canvas2.toDataURL(1.0);
  var workbook = new $.ig.excel.Workbook.load('/ExcelFile/test123.xlsx'); //  <- Here is my Problem
  var sheet = workbook.worksheets(1);

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length + 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < data[i - 1].length + 1; j++) {
      if (data[i - 1][0] == "Slaes rate of electricity") {
        sheet.getCell('B7').value('Plant');
        sheet.getCell('F7').value('℃');
        sheet.getCell('G7').value(Number(Price));
      } else if (data[i - 1][0] == "Annual average ambient Temp") {
        sheet.getCell("B8").value('Annual average ambient Temp');
        sheet.getCell('F8').value('℃');
        sheet.getCell('G8').value(Number(Price));
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Save the workbook
  saveWorkbook(workbook, "Formatting.xlsx");
}

function saveWorkbook(workbook, name) {
  workbook.save({
    type: 'blob'
  }, function(data) {
    saveAs(data, name);
  }, function(error) {
    alert('Error exporting: : ' + error);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can not save data by JS in a browser. (it is sandboxed, caused by security reasons!)
Therefor you have to prepare a download link. Otherwise you can use express or polka to create a local stand-alone executable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought it would be possible to load here at https://www.igniteui.com/help/javascript-excel-library-read-an-excel-2007-xlsx-file-into-a-workbook. But I don't know what fileData means here. Do you happen to know the answer?

Comment: In this example the excel-sheet is already loaded and represented as fileData. Read the file with a snippet like this: https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs . The result is your fileData.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't require('fs') because I'm currently working on the client side, not on the server side. Is there any other way?

Comment: This handling is for filestreams, even if the file is a requested object from anywhere. I recommend reading.. e.g. this https://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ ;)